# MySQL Void Query

Tags: mysql, sql, void

In MySQL, is there a way to make a query that does nothing but returns no error when executed?

Comment: can you please tell me guys why this statements are used. means for what purpose we need to null or NO results

Comment: Without going into details, I need to process a query and "I have to" return the processed query. If the process fails I have to return a query anyway to the layer above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `limit 0` on any query

```
select 0 limit 0
```

It executes but return no records